# Can i use Hyper-V VM Live-Migrating in a non Domain Environment

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012, live-migration

Does Hyper-V 3.0 require the Hosts to be joined to a Domain for Livemigrating? 
If so, i suspect that the VM's don't have this requirement?
Are ther additional Features i can't use in a Non-Domain/Sandalone Environment with Hyper-V Hosts?

Comment: I believe that any type of LiveMigration (LM, Move VM, Shared Nothing LM) require the Hyper-V hosts to be members of the same AD domain or be members of AD domains that trust each other. There is no requirement that the VM's belong to the any AD domain.

Answer (score 1):

The hosts must belong to the same Active Directory domain, or belong to domains that trust each other if you want live migration. I couldn't find any workaround. If your hosts are members of a domain, you can use kerberos authentication for replication, failover clustering, etc.